# How to structure base class where derived classes operate on different data types

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++17

I have a class that is supposed to fetch an object from the server.

```
// T types
struct RequestLicense
{
    // arbitrary data
};
struct RequestTrial
{
    // arbitrary data
}

// U types
struct LicenseData
{
    // arbitrary data
};
struct TrialData
{
    // arbitrary data
}

struct Fetcher
{
    template <typename T>
    std::wstring FetchBlob(T requestParameters);
    
    template <typename U>
    std::unique_ptr<U> DeserializeBlob(const std::wstring& serializedBlob);

    template <typename U>
    bool ValidateResponse(U* deserializedResponse);
    
    // Many different virtual, helper functions that make use of the types T and U
}

struct LicenseFetcher : Fetcher
{ 
    // overrides for the different helper functions mentioned in Fetcher
}

struct TrialFetcher : Fetcher
{
    // overrides for the different helper functions mentioned in Fetcher
}

// specialization FetchBlob with T=RequestLicense
// specialization for DeserializeBlob and ValidateResponse with U=LicenseData

// specialization FetchBlob with T=RequestTrial
// specialization for DeserializeBlob and ValidateResponse with U=TrialData

// specializations for many of the helper functions. 2 specializations for each of the functions--one RequestLicense/LicenseData and one for RequestTrial/TrialData.
```

Normally I would make the functions virtual, but I can't since they are templated. As I see it, I have two options: 1) proceed with the route I am on or 2) remove the templating and leverage downcasting.

I was thinking about creating `LicenseBase` that `LicenseData` and `TrialData` would inherit from. As `LicenseData` and `TrialData` have nothing in common, `LicenseBase` would be empty. I would then replace all references to the template type `U` with a pointer to `LicenseBase`. Since each derived class would be operating on a known type, it would be safe to downcast within each overriden function. e.g. `LicenseFetcher::ValidateResponse(LicenseBase* r) { const LicenseData& data = static_cast<const LicenseData&>(r); }` I would do something similar for the `Request*` types.

I know downcasting is frowned upon and it also wouldn't help when I am returning one of these types (like with `DeserializeBlob`) but I was wondering about future development. All this templatization seems a bit hard to follow, and downcasting would make it easier to read. Also, with the templated approach, `Fetcher.h` will grow quite large as it will contain a specialization for every function for each derived class. I already have a half-dozen functions that would need specialization and a half-dozen derived versions of `Fetcher`. As I type this out, templating seems like the right way to go, but I've been doing some templatization recently and a bit worried I'm starting to "view every problem as a nail."

Are there any options I'm missing? Or should I forge ahead with templating?

**Edit:** Regardless of the approach I take, I plan on having non-member functions like `GetLicense` and `GetTrial` that would look something like

```
LicenseData GetLicense()
{
    const RequestLicense params = RequestLicense(/*arbitrary parameters*/);
    std::wstring response = FetchBlob(params);
    std::unique_ptr<LicenseData> data = DeserializeBlob<LicenseData>(response);
    if (ValidateResponse<LicenseData>(data))
    {
        return data;
    }
    return {};
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `DeserializeBlob` return `std::variant` or `std::any`? I assume the serialized blob has some type ID encoded so you don't decode it into the wrong type.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that up. See my edit for more details, but I am planning on being able to know what type to deserialize the blob into based on the flow.

Comment: Why are you using pointers? (N)RVO would save from you any copy/move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would make the whole `Fetcher` structure a template, with the member functions being abstract virtual functions:

```
// R is the request type
// D is the data type
template <typename R, typename D>
struct Fetcher
{
    virtual std::wstring FetchBlob(R const& requestParameters) = 0;
    
    virtual std::unique_ptr<D> DeserializeBlob(const std::wstring& serializedBlob) = 0;

    virtual bool ValidateResponse(D const& deserializedResponse) = 0;

    // ...
};
```

Then when inheriting from it pass the specific types:

```
struct LicenseFetcher : public Fetcher<RequestLicense, LicenseData>
{
    std::wstring FetchBlob(RequestLicense const& requestParameters) override
    {
        // TODO: Implementation
    }
    
    std::unique_ptr<LicenseData> DeserializeBlob(const std::wstring& serializedBlob) override
    {
        // TODO: Implementation
    }

    bool ValidateResponse(LicenseData const& deserializedResponse) override
    {
        // TODO: Implementation
    }

    // ...
};
```

Would be much cleaner than having a multitude of specializations.

Comment: Thanks! The one issue I'm having with this solution is that I would like to make FetchBlob virtual instead of purely virtual (I know I'm changing requirements on you since I didn't mention this in my question.) All the logic for fetching for the different classes is identical (check if there is internet, etc) except for the parameters themselves. I want FetchBlob to call CreateRequest(Header/Body) (which would be purely virtual) and then each derived class would handle the creation of the header and body using the passed in parameters. Is there a way to modify your strategy to achieve this?

Comment: @janovak That's not a problem. Just change `FetchBlob` to not be virtual at all, implement it in the base template class, and call the virtual functions (using the `R` template) like any other function. Override them in the child-classes as shown in my example (with the actual types).

Comment: I was thinking I would run into issues since "Member function templates cannot be declared virtual." After trying it out in a smaller project I see that it compiles fine!

Comment: @janovak It works because with my solution the member functions are not templates, the whole class is. :)